# java application response is too long ,how does this flame graph implies?

Tags: java, linux, flamegraph

Here is a java application which accepts picture uploaded using base64, next to request another service by the base64, but the response time is too long, above 4-20s.

What does the graph implies?

[image: this is java application,which accepts picture uploaded using base64,next to request another service by the base64,but the response time is too long,above 4-20s]

Comment: I am sorry but your question is totally unclear to me. First what does the "flame graph "display? Second why do you post it - StackOverflow is about code, not graphs. Therefore edit your question and post the servlet code that causes the problems.

Comment: The flamegraph is not generated properly, there are some Java JIT related symbols not fixed. Please checkout the following link, and you will know what I mean by not generated properly https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/java-in-flames-e763b3d32166